# What is an example of an expression that does not produce a value?

Tags: c++

The c++ defines the expression as

> "An expression is a sequence of operators and their operands, that
>   specifies a computation. **Expression evaluation may produce a result**"

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions

Are there any expressions that does not produce a result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

Any expression that produces a result of type void. The most obvious would be evaluating a call to a function that returns void. That will (at least normally) have some side effects, but it won't produce a value as its result.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() { std:cout << "foo\n"; }

int main() { 
    foo(); // evaluating this expression produces no result
}
```

Comment: In javascript the function always returns a value. Thats why the definition of expression for javascript is "An Expression is any valid unit of code that resolves to a value". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)0;
```

You can cast any expression to the type **void** to erase the expression result.